# percentage of two column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two column amount, paid, the percentage I want to calculate the percentage of pay. how many percents paid the amount
as

```
amount  |  paid  | percent
100     |  90    | 90%
8000    | 4000   | 50%
50      | 100    |-50%
```

I want PostgreSQL query please help me

Comment: Paid 100 of 50, shouldn't that be 200%?

Comment: `select amount, paid, paid * 100 / amount from tableneme`